# Assimp 4 Loading Missing materials doesn't throw errors

Tags: c++, assimp

I'm using Assimp 4.1.0 to load OBJ files. Some files might be referencing a missing material file and i wanted to give my own default values to the materials if Assimp doesn't find them properly.

Given the documentation:

```
aiMaterial* mat = .....
// The generic way
if(AI_SUCCESS != mat->Get(<material-key>,<where-to-store>)) {
   // handle epic failure here
}
```

It should throw something, but it isn't. It is returning aiReturn_SUCCESS even though the material file wasn't there. Does anyone have any workaround for this ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the material in your example is not there it will be a nullptr-type and your application will crash. When no obj-based material were imported (the file with the mtl-extension ) a base material ill be created I guess this material file will be used to get the key which you want to look for.

First make sure that you are using the right material instance. Then the API will work as descriped in the API-documentation.

Just ask if there are still some open questions. And you will get faster answers if you are using the project-side directly :-).

Kim

Comment: But it seems Assimp is creating a collection of materials based on the ones the OBJ refers to, even tho it didnt found any definition for that material (it is defaulting to 0.0 for ambient, 0.6 for diffuse and 0.0 for specular components). The material pointers are not null.

It definetely creates a DefaultMaterial (with this exact name) and that i can handle, but it also carries all the other undefined materials and gives default values of its own

Comment: Yes, at the moment we are creating a default material. There is already an issue report opened to adress this.